# Expanding observations from a range to form a panel

Tags: stata

I currently have a data set that appears as follows

```
mnbr    uact_id   hiredate   termdate
9       3709      19510101   20000915
20      9409      20001001   20080601
33      25646     19990201   20000731
```

`mnbr` represents the member number of a given worker in a labor union.  `uact_id` is the shop they were working for and `hiredate` and `termdate` (given yyyymmdd) represent the given dates they were at the shop/`uact_id`.  I am currently trying to use the `expand` command in Stata to create a panel such that there is one observation per year for each member number (`mnbr`) between the indicators of `hiredate` and `termdate`.

i.e. it should ideally look like

```
mnbr    uact_id   year
9       3709      1951
9       3709      1952
9       3709      1953
9       3709      1954
```

etc. for each member number for each year.

Comment: So what is your code so far? Are `hiredate` and `termdate` numeric or string?

Comment: Disappointing not to see code. What did "trying to use `expand`" amount to?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming arbitrarily that the dates are strings, we can go

```
gen year = real(substr(hiredate, 1, 4))
gen duration = real(substr(termdate, 1, 4)) - year + 1
expand duration
bysort mnbr : replace year = year[_n-1] + 1 if _n > 1
```

If the dates are numeric, specifically integers, then the first two lines could be

```
gen year = floor(hiredate/10000)
gen duration = floor(termdate/10000) - year + 1
```

The `replace` step is discussed within 
[How can I replace missing values with previous or following nonmissing values or within sequences?](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/replacing-missing-values/index.html)

Comment: Thank you, I initially had been able to floor the hiredate and termdate (data type is long) but was not aware of the replace command.  My apologies for not posting my code to begin with, yours worked perfectly and thank you again for your assistance.